# How injected HttpContext in middleware?

Tags: c#, dependencies, code-injection, httpcontext

In asp net core (middlware) we have  :

app.Run(async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("hello"));

I have a question: how context injected in asp net core?

I tried to create the method MyRun() and to get the same result, but I didn't succeed.

app.MyRun(async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("hello"));

public static class MyRunExtension
{

```
    public static void MyRun(this IApplicationBuilder app, MyRequestDelegate handler)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));
        }

        app.Use(handler => handler);
    }

}
```

and
....
public delegate Task MyRequestDelegate(HttpContext context);

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are going to create your own middleware class, aren't you? If so, hope this link containing the detailed description of it, helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Its works with app.Use((context, next) => handler(context));

Comment: In this updated implementation, we use the app.Use method with the signature that takes a Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task> as its argument. Inside the lambda expression, we pass both context and next, although we don't actually use the next delegate. This way, the Use method accepts our middleware correctly.

Now, when you use app.MyRun(async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("hello")) in your Startup.cs, it will add your custom middleware to the pipeline, and "hello" will be sent as the response when a request comes in.